# Unable to create driver instance for Edge driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, qaf

Code is working fine for chrome but for Edge I'm facing issue

I have set below properties in application.properties file

```
driver.name=edgeDriver
webdriver.edge.driver = drivers/msedgedriver.exe
```

I have also downloaded edgedriver.exe as per current version of my edge browser
Edge Version : Version 89.0.774.63

When I am trying to execute the test I am seeing below messages in console log

> Unable to get class
> com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.TestStepExporter from jar
> /C:/Users/piyush/.m2/repository/com/qmetry/qaf/3.0.0/qaf-3.0.0.jar
> [QAFTestBase] - Initializing
> Driver...browser_str:edgeDriver,base_url:https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/,sel_server:localhost,port:4444
>
> [UiDriverFactory] - Driver: edgeDriver Mar 26, 2021 3:25:36 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities edge INFO: Using `new EdgeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.edge()`
>
> Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of
> 30 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout'
> appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization
> failure.Unable to Create Driver Instance for edge:
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.(java.net.URL,
> org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities)
>
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
> '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>
> System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
> '10.0', java.version: '11.0.10'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Answer (score 1):

Referred to [how to use edgeDriver with qaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354345/how-to-use-edgedriver-with-qaf)

it seems the property webdriver.edge.driver should be appended with "system" prefix. That means:

```
system.webdriver.edge.driver = drivers/msedgedriver.exe
```

After this, Page launched successfully